# Python: Zeep library is returning a list instead of a zeep object

Tags: python, soap, zeep, xmltodict

I'm using zeep to work with SOAP API, but the response returned from the service is a list and not a zeep object.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm having to use `raw_response=True` so i can get the xml on the 'text' attribute and transform it to a dict using the [xmltodict](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) library to be able to manipulate the data, but I would like to get the zeep object instead.

Sorry, I can't give you info about the wsdl.

Comment: hi @guilherme, please don't paste images of code, paste the code directly, as font. This will help users to reproduce, analyze and solve your problem.

Comment: You might want to make an effort to improve your questions and add some details that are useful to understand what issue you are facing. Right now you question is unanswerable.

Comment: As a clean workaround, You can leverage Zeep's plugin system to perform envelope modification (such as what you're doing with the transform). https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/plugins.html